# How to hide title bar from the beginning

Tags: android, titlebar

I am using following code to replace title bar.

```
    final boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

And it's working fine once UI loaded. Problem is however when I start the app, the ugly gray bar appears for 1-2 seconds until UI loaded. Is there any way to specify not showing the default title bar at all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want the titlebar to be gone in every `activity` within your app, then add

```
<application android:name=".YourAppNameHere" 
             android:label="@string/app_name" 
             android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

to your manifest. Not 100% sure though that this will prevent the titlebar from showing up momentarily, but it should work.

Comment: I can confirm that the titlebar won't ever show using that theme.

Answer (score 4):

In the Manifest file, add this line inside the `application` tag

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

It will hide the bar from all the activities. If you want to hide it from a specific activity, add the same line to that activity's tag.

Good Luck !

Comment: If you want to keep a white background use @android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a line to your AndroidManifest which states that you use a theme (standard android or extended)

```
<application android:name=".YourAppNameHere" 
         android:label="@string/app_name" 
         android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
         android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

and then you can have a themes.xml in your res/values/ folder where you extend the: Theme.NoTitleBar and add custom rules to them (for example like windowBackground)

```
<resources>
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_background</item>
  </style>
<resources>
```

Have fun